# Completions stopped working after upgrading zsh

Tags: zsh, upgrade, autocomplete

Previously I have been using this handy script with `oh-my-zsh` to set the tab color whenever I ssh into a machine:

```
# iTerm2 window/tab color commands
#   http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/ProprietaryEscapeCodes
tab-color() {
    echo -ne "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;$1\a"
    echo -ne "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;$2\a"
    echo -ne "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;$3\a"
}
tab-reset() {
    echo -ne "\033]6;1;bg;*;default\a"
    trap - INT EXIT
}

# Change the color of the tab when using SSH
# reset the color after the connection closes
color-ssh() {
    if [[ -n "$ITERM_SESSION_ID" ]]; then
        trap "tab-reset" INT EXIT
        if [[ "$*" =~ "production|ec2-.*compute-1" ]]; then
            tab-color 255 0 0
        else
            tab-color 144 181 80 #0 255 0
        fi
    fi
    ssh $*
}
compdef _ssh color-ssh=ssh

alias ssh=color-ssh
```

However, today I have discovered that the autocomplete is now broken! My `ssh` no longer autocompletes if I run this script. How do I diagnose what is going on?

Edit:
Disabling `oh-my-zsh` and sourcing the file leads to the error: `command not found: compdef`.

Comment: Starting with removing/disabling `oh-my-zsh` and see if it still happens is a good first step.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the problem. I've edited the question.

Comment: This is (almost) totally unrelated to the point of your question (that's why I'm writing this as a comment and not an answer), but — I'm totally unfamiliar with `zsh` or `oh-my-zsh`.  Are they POSIX compliant?  Because, in any POSIX-compliant shell, if a function wraps a program, and invokes that program with all of the arguments that were passed to the function, it should use *`program-name `* `"$@"` instead of *`program-name `* `$*`

Answer (score 16):

Ok, I've found the solution: deleting all `zcompdump` files solved the problem:

```
rm ~/.zcompdump*
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran the following and it fix the tab completion.

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
autoload -U bashcompinit && bashcompinit
```

Comment: I had some frustrations then they were fixed by putting `autoload -U compaudit && compinit` at the bottom of my `~/.zshrc`. (It was up higher in the file, before)